# spring boot chaos monkey not working with feign

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

I am testing the spring boot chaos monkey with feign ,hystrix and ribbon. It is not working. Calls are not failing as expected.

```
organizationService:
  ribbon:
    MaxAutoRetries: 2
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 0
    OkToRetryOnAllOperations: true
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 2000
    ConnectTimeout: 10000
    ReadTimeout: 1000
```

chaos config:

```
chaos:
    monkey:
        enabled: true
        watcher:
            controller: false
            restController: false
            service: false
            repository: true
            component: true

        assaults:
            level: 1
            latencyActive: true
            latencyRangeStart: 11000
            latencyRangeEnd: 40000
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal working example? Or provide some more details, which version of spring boot chaos monkey do you use?

Comment: I made it working after moving the code to the seperate class. I think Hystrix and Chaos monkey both uses the AOP . so not working together on the same method.

Comment: That is true. Did you know that hystrix is not maintained anymore? I would start switching to resilience4j at some point, maybe they're using something different than AOP.